# english bibliography when main language is not english with polyglossia

Tags: biblatex, polyglossia

I use `lualatex`,  or `xelatex`, and `biber`and `bibaltex`and `polyglosia` to compile my document. 
**I prefer to load biblatex first if possible.**
I want the french language as main language for the document, but I want the british language as main language for the bibliography. 
My problem is that my bibliography, which is all in english, is displayed with french words, instead of english words.

This is the order that I load things:

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=ieee-alphabetic, language=british]{biblatex}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
```

this is what prints the citations

```
\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
\selectlanguage{english}
\printbibliography[title= Bibliography]
\endrefcontext
```

Loading biblatex after `polyglossia` does not change the french display of my english bibliography....
Also, no entry in my bibliography has a field `language={english}` and it would take too long to add this field manually.

Comment: Polyglossia support has been a bit complicated at times (and in fact there were quite some problems until recently). The `language` options had some issues that should be fixed in the upcoming version 3.4 (see [issue #385](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/385) as well as [How to switch the bibliography to English in a document with another default language?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299726/35864) which may very well be a duplicate)

Comment: You can make your problem much easier to investigate for other people if you provide a full compilable example (an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)) and not just some snippets of code people need to piece together not knowing if their result remotely resembles what you have.

Comment: Your first problem is that `biblatex` really needs to be loaded *after* `polyglossia`. Is there any real reason why you prefer to load it earlier?

Comment: @moewe is correct, you *must* load biblatex after polyglossia so that is can detect polyglossia and set up some internals.